# Bifurcate a string, removing the middle of the string instead of end

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting

I want something similar to [this question I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869287/truncate-string-but-remove-middle-of-string-instead-of-end) lead me to [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015804/3340763) where I tried to convert it from [php](/questions/tagged/php) to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) my attempt to convert it... failed very badly:

```
private string trimString(string str, int maxCharacters = 16)
{
        int textLength = str.Length;
        return str.Substring(maxCharacters/2, textLength-maxCharacters).Insert(maxCharacters/2,"...");
}
```

So doing `trimString("123456789", 9)` outputs `123...789` when I meant to do something like `123...012` or something similar.. I can't quite figure it out and I've tried many different versions mostly resulting in an input that is out of order.

If it's possible **I'd like it to be a simple function and not include other libraries or initializing a new object every call** as I plan on using this a lot in a quick session. I'd really like it not to cut off words and place the ellipses however this is not required.

Comment: So you want to remove the characters from middle of string, how many characters you want to remove and do you want to replace them with `.` ?  what about strings with even number of characters ? how would you define the middle then ?

Comment: So essentially you want first 3 and last 3 characters of string. Right?

Comment: Yes. Similar to my old phone's function of replacing a long string with the start of it, trimming the middle, and leaving the end untouched. For example doing "Bob needs those ... by 12:30 on Monday" or similar.

Comment: Mind someone explain why it was downvoted so I may improve for the future? I'd rather not create poor quality questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Substring(maxCharacters/2, textLength-maxCharacters)` into which you insert the `...` already has the characters that you don't want to see - `456789`. There's no way to fix it after that.

What you should do instead is to pick the prefix and the suffix, and join them together, like this:

```
private static string trimString(string str, int maxCharacters = 16) {
    if (str.Length <= maxCharacters) {
        return str;
    }
    var suffixLength = maxCharacters / 2;
    // When maxCharacters is odd, prefix will be longer by one character
    var prefixLength = maxCharacters - suffixLength;
    return string.Format(
        "{0}...{1}"
    ,   str.Substring(0, prefixLength)
    ,   str.Substring(str.Length-suffixLength, suffixLength)
    );
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/PRl6ST)

Comment: Good improvement on checking str.Length against maxCharacters, since that optional argument has a default value.

Comment: Though I like smaller functions such as the two line version you initially had this works majorly better although I'm a bit saddened that C# isn't quite as simple as PHP in this case.

Answer (score 1):

this returns `123...012` for `trimString("123456789012", 6)` the first and the last 3 characters, seperated with `...`.

```
public static string trimString(string str, int max = 16)
{
    if (str.Length <= max)
    {
        return str;
    }   
    return str.Substring(0, max / 2) + "..." + str.Substring(str.Length - max / 2, max / 2);
}
```

Comment: This is something like I had planned but couldn't quite do. I do like the fact it relies purely on substring and it should be a easy operation compared to the other function however in my instance it doesn't quite matter.