# Remove a string in the middle in php

Tags: php

I want to remove 10th character from right of this string .

```
    $string = '1230789456123';
```

Output should be  `123789456123`
Any idea

Comment: You mean the `0` on `4th` position?

Comment: Are you counting from left or right?

Comment: Is 0 in the middle of the String?

Comment: counting from right. so the 10th position

Comment: Related: [truncate string, but remove middle of string instead of end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16869287/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) along with [`strrev`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) function as

```
$string = '1230789456123';
$str = strrev($string);
$string = strrev(str_replace($str[9], '', $str));
echo $string;
```

What I'm doing over here is

1. Using [`strrev`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) I'm reversing string which will result into `3216549870321`
2. Using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) I'm finding the 10th position and replacing it with empty value
3. Once again reversing string using [`strrev`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php).And here it is what you want

Or simply use

```
$str=substr_replace($string,"",-10,0) ;
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/380331)

Comment: its not that i want to remove'0' i want to remove the 10th character from the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

use `substr_replace`. your output is remove `0` from the string. and it is at 10th postion from the end

```
$string = '1230789456123';
$str=substr_replace($string,"",-10,0);
echo $str;
```

Comment: i wan to count from the end of the string and remove the 10th position. thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?PHP 

    $string = '1230789456123';
    $str = substr_replace($string,'',3,1);
    echo $str;

?>
```

Comment: i wan to count from the end of the string and remove the 10th position. thnx in advance

Answer (score -1):

I didn't get your question. Do you want to replace the 10th characterer strating from the last character. For this you can use:

```
$string = '1230789456123';
$new='';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){
if((strlen($string)-$i)!==10){
$new.=$string[$i];
}
}
echo $new;
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: i want to remove the 10th character from the last in a string

Comment: @user3358839 The code simply does that. Check it out

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to remove a specific character from the string you can use a function like this one

```
<?php
$string = '1230789456123';
$stringTest = '';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){
    if($string[$i]!='9'){
         $stringTest .= $string[$i];
    }
}
$string = $stringTest;
print_r($string);
?>
```

Or you can do for a specific place in the like, for example, if you wish to remove the 10th character of a string:

```
<?php
$string = '1230789456123';
$stringTest = '';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){
    if($string[$i]!=$string[9]){
        $stringTest .= $string[$i];
    }
}
 $string = $stringTest;
print_r($string);
?>
```

I'm using PHP 7.4.33

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).